# Open textfile and get the data behind the colon in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

This is my Example list for you which is stored in a textfile:

```
DEVICE:           Test

HW-RELEASE:       Test

SERIAL-NUMBER:    Test

MAC-ADDRESS:      Test

IP-ADDRESS:       Test

IP-NETMASK:       Test

INTRANET-ADDRESS: Test

INTRANETMASK:     Test

VERSION:          Test

NAME:             Test

CONFIG-STATUS:    Test

FIRMWARE-STATUS:  Test

HW-MASK:          Test

FEATUREWORD:      Test

REGISTERED-WORD:  Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

FEATURE-LIST:     Test

TIME:            Test

HTTP-PORT:       Test

HTTPS-PORT:       Test

TELNET-PORT:      Test

TELNET-SSL-PORT:  Test

SSH-PORT:         Test

SNMP-PORT:        Test

TFTP-PORT:        Test

LOCATION:         Test

COUNTRY-CODE:     Test

COMMENT:          Test

MYVPN:            Test

MYVPN-HOSTNAME:   Test

EXTENDED-NAME:    Test
```

So I want to output the data behind the colon but always only one line of it. I want to define this line via a dictionary in the script so that I can for example only enter "Device" and it gives me the name after the colon so that the names in front of the colon should act as a key. As I do the whole instead I only know roughly what I have thought up so far. Unfortunately this code doesn't work as I would like it to:

```
data = {}

with open('C:/example/example/example/example/example.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
        data[key] = value

for x in data:
    print(x)
```

Output from this code is:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

What I expect is when I define something like:

```
x = data["DEVICE"]
```

it should output its value which is obviously "Test"

Comment: Show your expected result

Comment: What's the output of your code? Could you add it?

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: replace `for x in data: print(x)` with `for k, v in data.items(): print(k, v)`

Comment: This code was only to show the keys from the dictionary i defined. Just to look if there was anything in this list

Comment: `for k in data.keys():` if you want only the keys

Comment: Its the same result it doesnt matter if i change it. And this isnt my problem which i encounter

Comment: Which line/part of code outputs the `not enough values to unpack` error? I'm assuming it's the `key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)`, which looks fine to me if your data is correct.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ", line 5, in <module>
    key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: I really dont know why i am getting this error i tried hours already but i cant figure it out

Comment: Do you realize that only half the lines have a colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, could you try print what is in `line`?

If it is as expected (i.e. contain `DEVICE: Test`), make sure the whitespace handled correctly as follows.

```
for line in fh:
    if line.strip(): # Ignore blank lines
        key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(':', 1)]
        ...
```

Comment: Tell me what i have done wrong its now working. I really want to know what i have did wrong. And thanks for the help! to all of you!

Comment: My suspicion is that you have empty lines in the file and it couldn't be unpacked since it only contain empty string. The `key, value = ` expects data type like list or tuple with 2 elements and empty string is just empty string. Glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You are not skipping the empty lines.

If the example you posted is correct between to "entries" there is an empty line that you are trying to split:

try:

```
for line in fh:
   if line:
    key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
    data[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the format of your text file.

The empty lines between your value lines make `key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)` crash. Simply reformat your text file or handle empty lines accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
item = 'DEVICE'

filepath = '/home/will/testing/stuff.txt'

with open(filepath) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    data = [line for line in data if line != '']
    data_dict = {line.split()[0][:-1]:line.split()[1] for line in data}

print(data_dict[item])
# Test
```